# Reverse a string (x) amount of times?

Tags: java, while-loop

Before I get for loops etc and string buffers this **HAS** to be like this.. with a while loop and creating the string by manipulating it.. not with string buffers etc.

```
public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(rotate("tom", 3));
    }

    public static String rotate(String s, int n) {
        String c = "";

        do {
            if (s.equals("")) {
                return c;
            } else {
                c = s.charAt(0) + c;
                n--;
                System.out.println(n);

            }

            s = s.substring(1);
        } while (n > 0);
        return c;

    }
}
```

Pretty much as the title says.. I need the program to rotate the name "tom" n times.. so in this example 3 times.

it does it once and changes "tom" to "mot" BUT I have no idea how to change it back to "tom" for its second out of three times..
Anyone offer any tips?

Comment: `rotate(rotate(s)) == s`, btw.

Comment: Either only `rotate` if `n` is odd, or call `rotate` inside a loop.

Comment: Reverse, I'm sorry my english was pretty poor!

Answer (score 3):

This could be made very efficiently if you broke down the problem into two solutions! *(N being the number of times the string must be reversed!)*

- When N is even
- When N is odd

Now you should know after running a few examples that when N is even, the word reversed N times will just be the word itself! So :

```
if(N%2 == 0){
    return str;
}
```

When N is odd, you only have to reverse it once! There does not need to be a while loop which keeps reversing it N times since if N is odd, N-1 is even! And when reversed till N-1, the string should just return itself! So reversing it one more time will be the output you wish to desire.

so you add to that if statement above

```
else{
    //do reverse function
}
```

This makes it so that you dont have to keep reversing the string. You will only do it once, *IF AND ONLY IF* N is Odd!

Hope that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about *reversing*, you need to figure out a way to set `c` back to `s` again so that you can repeat the operation. Since you are doing a character-by-character reversal, you will need two loops: the inner loop will run from `0` to `str.length - 1`, and the other loop should run from `0` to `n - 1`.

There is a *much* easier way<sup>*</sup> but I imagine that your teacher wants you to do it this way to understand looping fundamentals.

<sup>*</sup>If `n % 2 == 0` then you only need to return `str` otherwise reverse.

Comment: Im sorry, my wording was pretty rubbish, reversing!

Comment: I know it's pretty silly but thats the task I was given.. N can be anything so it can be 1,2,3,4,5.. etc its just to show we can do it! Thank you!

Comment: @user3259071 Just implement the rotation functionality *once*. Then repeat that operation `n` times.